# How to check the text on an overlay using Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, popup, overlay

I'm clicking in on a button on a webpage using Selenium. The button creates a file which can be downloaded now. For this, a overlay is shown in Internet Explorer (yes, I HAVE to use this browser, it's a requirement).

Now I have to check the text on the overlay ("öffnen oder speichern" see my screenshot). I can imagine that it there is a solution using JavaScriptExecutor but I simply couldn't found a solution.

I also tried to find it in innerHTML-without success.

It's not an alert so I can't use Driver.switchTo().alert();

My Code still doesn't contain more than clicking on a button using XPath.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String exportButtonXPath = generalHelper.getProperty("buttonCSVExportXPath");
WebElement exportButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath(exportButtonXPath));
action.click(exportButton).perform();
```

Do you have a solution how can test the text on this popup?[image: n]

Comment: What does **öffnen oder speichern** means in english? What are the available options?

Comment: "öffnen und speichern" means open and save Options are "open", "save" and "abort".

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it is not related to the web browser any more. You need to interact with it as a desktop window.

->If you want to click it using selenium, you can locate its coordinates and use click by coordinates using selenium.

->If you want to accept to download it, you can find a capability to accept downloading by default (except IE).

->If you want to check the text value, for sure you've to automate it as desktop not as a web.